# calling private methods for class method: python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement multiple constructors in python and one of the suggestions (through online searching) was to use the classmethod. However, using this, I am having issues with code reuse and modularity. Here is an example where I can create an object based on a supplied file or through some other means:

```
class Image:

    def __init__(self, filename):
         self.image = lib.load(filename)
         self.init_others()

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data, header):
        cls.image = lib.from_data(data, header)
        cls.init_others()
        return cos

    def init_others(self):
        # initialise some other variables
        self.something = numpy.matrix(4,4)
```

Now it seems that I cannot do that. The cls.init_others() call fails by saying that I have not provided the object to call it on. I guess I can initialise things in the from_data function itself but then I repeat the code in the **init**  method and the other "constructors". Does anyone know how I can call these other initialiser methods from these @classmethod marked functions? Or perhaps someone knows a better way to initialise these variables.

I come from a C++ background. So still trying to find my way around the python constructs.

Comment: Your alternate conductor isn't creating an instance, but modifying the class.

Comment: But then I should be able to do cls.init_others() right?

Comment: No, because Image.init_others is an instance method, not a class method.  You have decorated the Image.from_data method as a class method; this means that the function can be called on both instances of Image and the class Image itself, but the first argument will always be the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class method should create and return a new instance of the class, not assign class attributes and return the class itself. As an alternative to the keyword arguments, you could do something like:

```
class Image:

    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.init_others()

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data, header):
        return cls(lib.from_data(data, header))

    @classmethod
    def from_filename(cls, filename):
        return cls(lib.load(filename))

    def init_others(self):
        # initialise some other variables
        self.something = numpy.matrix(4, 4)
```

This adds the ability to create an instance if you already have the `image`, too.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend *not* trying to create multiple constructors, and use keyword arguments instead:

```
class Image(object):
    def __init__(self, filename=None, data=None, header=None):
         if filename is not None:
             self.image = lib.load(filename)
         elif data is not None and header is not None:
             self.image = lib.from_data(data, header)
         else:
             raise ValueError("You must provide filename or both data and header")
         self.init_others()

    def init_others(self):
        # initialise some other variables
        self.something = numpy.matrix(4,4)
```

This is a more Pythonic way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You should always pass in `self` as the first argument to any method that will act on a class instance. Python will not automatically determine the instance you're trying to call the method for unless you do that. So if you want to use a class function like

```
the_image = Image("file.txt")
the_image.interpolate(foo,bar)
```

You need to define the method within `Image` as

```
def interpolate(self,foo,bar):
  # Your code
```

Comment: Sorry that was a type. I do pass self. Edited it now.